# How to client's windows login information in angular application hosted on IIS server?

Tags: javascript, angular, iis

Basically, I have developed an angular web application for my company and hosting it on IIS server that requires windows authentication. Server and client both are sitting in corporate network.
I am struggling to get client's windows login information in server side when the client logs into my application. How would I do that?
Is there any way in javascript that can get me client's login username?

Comment: According to this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-use I don't believe it's possible unless the user explicitly enters their windows user name

Answer (score 1):

Actually its possible to send windows username using the below flag in angular application:

```
return this.httpClient.get<UserDetails>(`${this.userInfoUrl}`, { withCredentials: true });
```

Adding that extra flag after url works for me.

But this is only possible in intra-network(corporate network where Microsoft Active Directory is enabled) and in IIS server windows authentication is enabled. Client and server both are in the same intra-network domain. Please comment if you find anything wrong with this.
Please comment if I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Angular(javascript) is a client-side web framework and as such cannot access the user's Windows login info.

Refer this link for more detail:

[Get Windows Username within Angular 2/4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066903/get-windows-username-within-angular-2-4-application)